# Is there a way to get the MATLAB version without starting the engine?

Tags: linux, matlab

Is there a way to get the version of MATLAB without launching the engine? When launched (in non-GUI mode) it prints the version to stout - but I am using it remotely from Java and so that output is not available.

As an alternative, is there a way to get the version from within MATLAB?

By 'version' I mean preferably the double-string number, e.g "7.13" as opposed to the release number e.g "R2011b".

Thanks!
James

Comment: Why can't you just use MATLAB's [`version`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/version.html) command from within your Java code?

Comment: How are you running matlab remotely? Can't you redirect stdout and stderr and use them?

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Because I don't want to launch the engine, as it says in my question.

Comment: @jgubby: I was obviously addressing your second question, not the first...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Oh yeah... oops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jonas said, the `version` command is your friend.  Use

```
v = version
```

to get the numeric version (followed by the "R-release" version) in a string, as follows:

```
v =
7.12.0.39132 (R2011a)
```

Then, you should be able to parse the string to get just the beginning numeric part.

See the MathWorks documentation for VERSION at

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/version.html

for more information.

An additional hint; if you're looking for the version number to ensure that the installed MATLAB is no older than (some particular release number), check out the documentation for VERLESSTHAN, at http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/verlessthan.html  It might help you solve your problem *without* having to parse the string yourself.

Comment: Close enough, thanks. Shame the creators of this $$$ software didn't think to make the version number available from a CL flag like in every other piece of software in the world....

Comment: @jgubby How does this solve your problem of getting the version without running the engine? You must have it running already to execute `version`. When running matlab on the commandline you can also get the version number from the header: `matlab -r quit | grep Version`

Comment: @stardt I just thought it was the closest to the right answer, since there didn't seem to be any way otherwise. Thats a cunning trick - except that R2011 has a different format, and doesn't seem to print the version with that string as a prefix. Probably too fragile, since I will forget that I've done that hack with 100% certainty...

Comment: `matlab -r quit -nojvm | grep "R201[0-9][ab]"` This seems to find it on Linux with 2014a and Mac OS X with 2017a

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the following works in all releases, but try running:

```
matlab -help
```

This displays the command line usage, and interestingly at the end, it print the version (MATLAB is not started in the process):

```
matlab [-? ^| -h ^| -help]
       [-c licensefile]
       [-nosplash]
       [-nodesktop ^| -nojvm]

<...TRUNCATED...>

    -shieldload <list>   - Win32 only: (experimental) loads dlls identified in
                                   comma separated list


    Version: 7.13.0,564
```

You could easily obtain the version number from that output (`grep` is your friend)

Comment: Matlab 2014 and 2015 on Linux do not seem to print it, but if the release version is part of the Matlab path, it will end up in `matlab -n`.